# Си вывод в консоль, но без записи в буфер

Tags: linux, c, bash, консоль

Если я использую `printf("asd")`, то весь текст в кавычках будет выведен на экран и записан в лог файл. Вот такая команда: `./a.out > file.log`. Есть ли какая другая команда вывода, которая будет текст выводить только в терминал, без записи в файл? Знаю, что можно записать через `fprintf` этот текст в отдельный файл, а потом просто вывести его на экран, в итоге в `file.log` его не будет. Но это уже какие-то танци с бубном. Или иначе никак...

Comment: Для вывода терминал, независимо от перенаправления стандартног выврда (stdout) можно открыть `/dev/tty` (`FILE *tty = fopen("/dev/tty", "w");`) и далее писать в него `fprintf(tty, "...", ...);`

Comment: Естественно, можно определить макрос, например -- `#define TTY(fmt ...) fprintf(tty, fmt)` и использовать его далее полностью как printf (в этом случае возможно имеет смысл сделать глобальный `FILE *tty;` (только не забудьте сделать для него fopen перед первым TTY(...))

Comment: Библиотека [`ncurses`](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/) позволяет не только банально выводить строки функцией `printw`, но и управлять цветами, выводить в разных точках терминала и даже рисовать окошки псевдографикой с кнопками и прочим блекджеком.

Comment: @avp, сделайте ответ. Информация полезна для линуксоидов, я про такое не думал. Надо будет буферизацию настроить.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, а что тут может быть не так с буферизацией? По умолчанию line buffered, как и любой терминал по умолчанию

Comment: @avp, как `fopen` узнает что "/dev/tty" ассоциирован с терминалом? Мне кажется что `tty` окажется `fully buffered` что не хорошо для интерактивного использования.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, в musl (одна из реализаций libc) fopen проверяет, что открывает терминал, вызывая ioctl (точнее `__syscall(SYS_ioctl, fd, TIOCGWINSZ, &wsz))` (можно посмотреть в http://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/stdio/__fdopen.c)  (вообще, там в кодах много интересного об внутреннем устройстве)

Comment: Лично я, как системный администратор, посылал бы лучи поноса автору программы, которая отказывается перенаправляться, каждый раз при её запуске.

Answer (score 2):

Пользуйтесь [stdout и stderr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/std_streams). Это стандартный для `C` способ:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        fprintf(stdout, "%d goes to log\n", i);
        fprintf(stderr, "%d goes to terminal\n", i);
    }
}
```

> ```
> $ gcc -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror temp.c 
>
> $ ./a.out >file.log
> 0 goes to terminal
> 1 goes to terminal
> 2 goes to terminal
> 3 goes to terminal
> 4 goes to terminal
> 5 goes to terminal
> 6 goes to terminal
> 7 goes to terminal
> 8 goes to terminal
> 9 goes to terminal
>
> $ cat file.log
> 0 goes to log
> 1 goes to log
> 2 goes to log
> 3 goes to log
> 4 goes to log
> 5 goes to log
> 6 goes to log
> 7 goes to log
> 8 goes to log
> 9 goes to log
> ```

**P.S.** Если проект крупный, подумайте над отдельной библиотекой для логирования.

Comment: stderr тоже может быть записан в файл `2>error.log` так что не уверен, что это то, о чём спрашивал автор вопроса (впрочем, возможно, автор вопроса просто не знал про stderr)

Comment: Так он и пользуется stdout (printf выводит как раз в него). При переадресации вывода (`>`) shell (после fork-а) связывает дескриптор 1 с файлом (по умолчанию он в shell-е адресует /dev/tty) , далее в startup-е программы FILE *stdout связывается с уже переадресованным дескриптором 1 и вывод printf отправляется в файл. Как-то так вся эта механика работает)

Answer (score 2):

В *nix-ах (и также в Linux) с каждым процессом  связан так называемый **[управляющий терминал](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/tty.4.html)**, который доступен программе через файл ***/dev/tty*** (ну, за исключением демонов, которые сами отказываются от него).

С этим файлом всегда связан реальный текстовый терминал (или псевдотерминал в системе с окошками или при удаленной работе по сети). Обычно это тот терминал из которого процесс был запущен.

*(вообще, о работе с терминалом в сети можно найти много статей, например, можно почитать [The Linux Text-Terminal-HOWTO](https://www.mit.edu/afs.new/athena/system/rhlinux/redhat-6.2-docs/HOWTOS/other-formats/html/Text-Terminal-HOWTO-html/Text-Terminal-HOWTO.html#toc6)).*

Таким образом, если требуется выводить сообщения в терминал, независимо от перенаправления (в файл или  pipe) `stdout` при запуске программы, вы можете открыть `/dev/tty` на запись и использовать `fprintf/fputs/fwrite` и т.д. для вывода сообщений.

Тривиальная программа может быть, например, такой:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  FILE *tty = fopen("/dev/tty", "w");
  fprintf(tty, "%s Start message\n", av[0]);

  printf("%s started\n", av[0]);

  fputs("Final message\n", tty);

  return puts("End") == EOF;
}
```

Далее все зависит от вашей фантазии.

Можно сделать переменную `tty` глобальной и написать макрос:

```
#define TTY(fmt ...) ({if (!tty) tty = fopen("/dev/tty", "w"); fprintf(tty, fmt);})
FILE *tty;
```

Тогда вы (в некоторой степени) смоделируете то поведение, которое присуще printf/puts (для которых stdout уже открыт в стартовом коде).

Кстати, что-то такое:

```
  int rc = TTY("tty output of %s\n", av[0]);
  
  TTY("rc = %d", rc);
  sleep(3);
  TTY("\n");
```

продемонстрирует, что fopen по умолчанию открывает терминал в line buffered режиме.